# Binding to a CollectionViewSource returns DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I need to make an item checked whether it is in use or not by a member of a collection.

When I bind directly to the collection (binding 2) it **does work** but not through a view of it (binding 3), it returns `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`.

Why isn't it working ?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="system:String">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox>
                <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AssetToBooleanConverter}" Mode="OneWay"  >
                        <Binding />
                        <Binding Path="Assets" Source="{StaticResource Singleton}" />
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource CvsAssets}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </CheckBox.IsChecked>
            </CheckBox>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PathToNameConverter}}"
                ToolTip="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PathToSizeConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the view of that collection :

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CvsAssets"
                        IsLiveSortingRequested="True"
                        Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource Singleton},
                                        Path=Assets}"
                        d:IsDataSource="True">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription Converter="{StaticResource ObjectToTypeNameConverter}" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fixed it using the following syntax :

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource CvsAssets}" Path="(CollectionView.SourceCollection)" />
```

(Debugger gave a warning about the binding **and the type** which was `ListCollectionView`)